# Яндекс.Касса: Платеж не прошел из-за технической ошибки

Tags: yandex-money, яндекс-касса

На самом сайте установлен выделенный IP и сертификат Comodo PositiveSSL (и дело не в форме отправления), но все равно всегда следующая картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать?

Comment: написать в ТП Яндекс.Касса

Comment: Написал, но они очень долго отвечают и перепроверяют один вариант за другим, которые не подходят.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, нужно было выполнить 2 условия, о которых мне написали:

"Вы некорректно передаете параметр customerContact. По протоколу данный параметр должен содержать в себе: номер телефона или эл. почту покупателя, а вы передаете набор цифр.
Ограничения:
1. Номер телефона в формате +79210000000 или адрес электронной почты (проверяется соответствие);
2. Следует передавать что-то одно: только адрес почты или только телефон;
3. Не следует передавать несколько адресов или телефонов.
Ссылка на взаимодействие с протоколом: https://tech.yandex.ru/money/doc/payment-solution/payment-form/payment-form-receipt-docpage/

А также вам необходимо добавить в платежную форму передачу параметра paymentType. 
Ссылка на взаимодействие с протоколом: https://tech.yandex.ru/money/doc/payment-solution/payment-form/payment-form-http-docpage/"